# How to upgrade Gradle to the latest version in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gradle

This is not a duplicate since the other question aren't related and don't solve the problem at hand like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920708/update-gradle-in-flutter-project)

Anyways, is there a way to upgrade `Gradle` to the latest version? I'm using `Flutter`

Comment: it's not about flutter. you have to update it inside android studio. here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html

Comment: The problem is finding the latest working version. I'm struggling with the same problem. I created a new flutter project a couple of months ago and it was created with gradle 4.1.3. I'm pretty sure it will break if I update to the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

You can let Flutter determine the gradle version for the Android build. Make sure that the Flutter version that you're using is up-to-date by running `flutter upgrade`. Then delete the `/android` folder inside the Flutter project. Regenerate the Android build by running `flutter create --platforms=android`

Answer (score 0):

Open the flutter project in Android studio then go to android directory inside it their is a build.gradle open it then android studio would have an option to open in android studio view, open it, android  studio would download needed Gradle version, then would tell you to update to latest version.

this is my current build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}