# when I am trying to add fb login authentication getting error stating A problem occurred configuring root project 'cloud_firestore'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'cloud_firestore'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\rajesh\Desktop\Flutter learning\loginsignup\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:66: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.example.loginsignup:string/app_name) not found.

Comment: app level build.gradle :   defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.loginsignup"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName 
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: Please change `compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30`

Comment: Even that is also not working getting same error

Comment: can you share console

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-in-android-studio/

Comment: VSCODE:          FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'cloud_firestore'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s


Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: update gradle version and should work fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920708/update-gradle-in-flutter-project

Comment: could you please explain to me clearly i am unable to update gradle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil