# Why can´t Flutter apply plugin "com.android,internal.version-check"?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I´m using Visual Studio Code and android studio emulator. If I debug my project this happens:
I have the same problem with new and old  projects.
It is  a normal project only with the normal "You have pushed the button this many times" code...
If I use other types of debugging like Webdebug or Windowsdebug it is working.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:60092/vedbJy-KzUE=/ws
I/com.example.fi( 3652): WaitForGcToComplete blocked RunEmptyCheckpoint on ProfileSaver for 5.648ms
Unhandled exception:
type 'DillSetterBuilder' is not a subtype of type 'SourceMemberBuilderImpl?' in type cast
#0      SourceLibraryBuilder.checkMemberConflicts.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_library_builder.dart:998:22)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:574:13)
#2      Scope.forEachLocalSetter (package:front_end/src/fasta/scope.dart:424:14)
#3      SourceLibraryBuilder.checkMemberConflicts (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_library_builder.dart:974:11)

#4      SourceLibraryBuilder.build (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_library_builder.dart:1057:5)
#5      IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1817:20)
#6      IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1668:39)
#7      CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:46)
#8      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:296:31)
#9      CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:118:19)
#10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
#11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#12     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1861:10)
#13     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1783:10)
#14     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:117:12)
#15     IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:1668:26)
#16     IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:218:23)
#17     FrontendCompiler.compileExpression (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:850:44)
#18     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1268:20)
#19     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1160:15)
#20     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)

#21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)

#22     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#23     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)
#24     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)
#25     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)
#26     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:170:13)
#27     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:145:5)
#28     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:163:5)
#29     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
#30     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)
#31     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#32     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#33     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)
#34     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)
#35     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)
#36     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:243:7)
#37     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:317:20)
#38     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5)
#39     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
#40     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
#41     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)
#42     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#43     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#44     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)
#45     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)
#46     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
#47     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2314:41)
#48     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:10)
#49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#50     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#51     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)
#52     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)
#53     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
#54     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1839:33)
#55     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1322:14)
#56     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#57     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#58     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:122:13)
#59     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:193:5)

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Exited (1)
```

Do someone has an idea how to solve my problem??
Mats

Comment: This has been already answered, please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920708/update-gradle-in-flutter-project

Comment: I have the same problem with new projects. There not. But  thx